# How to calculate Max Retries and Retry backoff configuration for Confluent cloud http sink connector?

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

There is below configuration for Confluent Cloud HTTP Sink connector:

```
max.retries=20
retry.backoff.ms=10000
retry.on.status.codes=500-
```

How to calculate the max retries and backoffs value if I want to retry until next 72 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retry handling code is internal to confluent, and this is a bug on confluent's http connector connect-util.3.x.x.jar file. This has been communicated to confluent and they are looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set retries to 1 and backoff to 259,200,000 or anything in between to meet your requirement of 72 hours.